# display data in blank array javascript. <div>

Tags: javascript

So far I have been able to come up with something like this. And i have been able to send something to an array, but in the display, thats what i have not been able to achieve so far.

Hence i am asking, How do i display it?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <script type=text/javascript>
    var array = [];

    function add_element_to_array() {
        array.push(document.getElementById("institution_name").value);
        array.push(document.getElementById("degree_obtained").value);
        array.push(document.getElementById("honors_acheieved").value);

        document.getElementById("institution_name").value = "";
        document.getElementById("degree_obtained").value = "";
        document.getElementById("honors_acheieved").value = "";
    }

function display_array()
{
    // Display array
}

    </script>
</head>
<title>Test Javascript</title>
<h1>Test JS</h1>

<body>
    <form name="xform" id="xform" method="post" action="samris.php" /> Institution Name:
    <input type="text" name="institution_name" id="institution_name" /> </br>
    Degree Obtained:
    <input type="text" name="degree_obtained" id="degree_obtained" />
    </br>
    Honors Achieved:
    <input type="text" name="honors_acheieved" id="honors_acheieved" />
    </br>
    </p>
    <input type="button" name="Add" id="add" value="add" onclick="add_element_to_array()" />
    </form>
    <div onload= display_array()>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You want to just display the content of the array as a plain text in the `<div>` ?

Comment: @HamzaAbdaoui, yes.. it should get the input as array and display in div, so yes...

Answer (score 0):

To display array:

```
function display_array(){
    var display = array.join('<br>');
    this.innerHTML = display; // only works if you call it inline (except onload).

    /* OR */

    // works everywhere when you add an id to the div except onload (see explanation below).
    document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = display;
}

/* ... in the HTML ... */
<div id="display"></div>
```

However you will still not able to display it in the `div` because of the `onload=display_array()`.

When the `div` is being loaded, `display_array()` will be called. However when it is being loaded, `array` is still empty because nothing has been added to it yet by `onclick=add_element_to_array()`.

To do that, you can call `display_array()` from within `add_element_to_array()` like so:

```
function add_element_to_array(){
    /*
      your code
    */

    display_array();
}
```

Alternatively, you need to remove the `onclick` and replace by `addEventListener` in your `<script>`. However, you will need to move your `<script>` tag to the bottom of your `<body>` tag or otherwise implement a function similar to jQuery's `ready()`.